# Bubble Chart plot area exported to png gets cut out using a customized theme in packcicles

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bubble-chart

I want to create a chart with the package packcircles as well as ggplot. and export it with the print device I use in this case "ragg".

I have two issues

When I export the chart to a png file , the chart gets squeezed into half of the plotting area. The exported chart must be a square and The title should fit into the whole plotting area.

The text inside the bubbles , I want to be able to resize it so it fits the size of the bubbles. And want to add another numeric text (column/variable:ptg) to each bubble with a different size.

I have tried this:

```
    theme_bubble <- function( ) {
  
    theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill ="gray80"),
    panel.grid.major.y  = element_line(color = "gray80"),
    panel.grid.major.x  = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill="gray80"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"),
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_textbox(size=35,color="white",vjust=1,
                                 family = "merriweather",width = unit(1, "npc"),
                                 margin= margin(r=-40,b=80),
                                 lineheight = 1.3),
    plot.subtitle = element_textbox_simple(size=20,color="grey80",
                                           margin= margin(t=10,b=28,r=-40),
                                           family = "montserrat",
                                           width = unit(1, "npc")),
    plot.caption.position = "plot",
    plot.caption = element_textbox(size=12,color="grey85",margin= margin(t = 10, b=10,r=60),
                                   lineheight = 1.2,
                                   family = "montserrat",
                                   width = unit(1, "npc")),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,0,1),"cm"),

    
    
  )
}
######

df1 <- data.frame(birds = c("Eagle", "Owl", "Falcon", "Ostrich", "Blue Jay"),
                 values = c(46, 29, 55, 100, 17),
                 ptg = c(20,10,15,30,25))


df1$packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(df1$values, sizetype='area')

df1.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(df1$packing, npoints=50)

tp <- "Headline news august 23 2023, boldface"
c1 <- "Source: WWW "


p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = df1.gg, aes(x, y, group = id, fill=id), alpha = 0.6)+
  labs(title = tp,
       caption = c1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()+
  geom_text(data = df1, aes(x=packing$x, y=packing$y, label = birds), size=5, color="black") +
  theme_bubble() + 
  coord_equal()


agg_png("prue.png", width = 10, height = 10, units = "in", res = 300)
p
dev.off()
```

I get this:

[image]